# How to pass map annotation on segue to mapView on another vc?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I currently have a map with annotation and would like to pass this to another map on another VC (replicate the map). How can I do this in my prepare for Segue function?

In my current map VC

```
    if segue.identifier == "addEntrySegue",
        let addEntryVC = segue.destination as? AddEntryViewController
    {
        addEntryVC.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05,0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(annotation.coordinate, span)
        addEntryVC.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    }
```

Comment: how have you tried to do that so far?

Comment: i hav edited the q @holex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea of passing data in `prepare(for:sender:)` is correct.

Obviously, you will want to make sure that the identifier and the cast of the view controller were successful, perhaps by adding a breakpoint inside that `if` statement. I would have thought that if this `if` statement was successful, that you would have crashed when you tried to interact with `mapView` at this point, so I wonder if this `if` statement is succeeding at all. If it isn't succeeding, you'll want to double check (a) the spelling and capitalization of the storyboard identifier that you specified for the segue in IB; and (b) that the base class of the destination scene is really `AddEntryViewController`.

But, even if you confirm that the `if` statement is working properly, you cannot just update `UIKit` controls of the destination view controller in `prepare(for:sender:)`, because they haven't been created yet. Thus, you can't reference the map view in `prepare(for:sender:)`.

You should have an annotation property in your `AddEntryViewController`, and the `prepare` should simply set that. Then, in `viewDidLoad` of `AddEntryViewController`, by which point the views *have* been created, add that annotation to the map view and set the region/camera.